# Jhipster authentication with Azure AD (Entra ID) token for Security

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, jhipster

I meet a problem during my development because I have a connection to a Azure AD (Azure Entra ID) in my React code.

[I put the token receive by the front like this in the call api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmMFe.png)

But I got an error 401 Unauthorized directly.

So I change lightly my SecurityConfiguration to permitAll on all Endpoint for testing my jwt Token. Here is my SecurityConfiguration after the change. It doesn't change since the generation of the project. I have generated the project with a Keycloak configuration for information.

```
package com.sanofi.trialsetup.config;

import com.sanofi.trialsetup.security.*;
import com.sanofi.trialsetup.security.SecurityUtils;
import com.sanofi.trialsetup.security.oauth2.AudienceValidator;
import com.sanofi.trialsetup.security.oauth2.CustomClaimConverter;
import com.sanofi.trialsetup.security.oauth2.JwtGrantedAuthorityConverter;
import java.util.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.GrantedAuthoritiesMapper;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUserAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.*;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationConverter;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice.security.SecurityProblemSupport;
import tech.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties;

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuerUri;

    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;

    public SecurityConfiguration(CorsFilter corsFilter, JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport) {
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
        this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return web ->
            web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
                .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
                .antMatchers("/content/**")
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**")
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**")
                .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
                .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
        .and()
            .headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getContentSecurityPolicy())
        .and()
            .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
        .and()
            .permissionsPolicy().policy("camera=(), fullscreen=(self), geolocation=(), gyroscope=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=(), midi=(), payment=(), sync-xhr=()")
        .and()
            .frameOptions()
            .deny()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth-info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/health/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .and()
            .oauth2Login()
        .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter())
                .and()
            .and()
                .oauth2Client();
        return http.build();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> authenticationConverter() {
        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new JwtGrantedAuthorityConverter());
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }

    /**
     * Map authorities from "groups" or "roles" claim in ID Token.
     *
     * @return a {@link GrantedAuthoritiesMapper} that maps groups from
     * the IdP to Spring Security Authorities.
     */
    @Bean
    public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return authorities -> {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            authorities.forEach(authority -> {
                // Check for OidcUserAuthority because Spring Security 5.2 returns
                // each scope as a GrantedAuthority, which we don't care about.
                if (authority instanceof OidcUserAuthority) {
                    OidcUserAuthority oidcUserAuthority = (OidcUserAuthority) authority;
                    mappedAuthorities.addAll(SecurityUtils.extractAuthorityFromClaims(oidcUserAuthority.getUserInfo().getClaims()));
                }
            });
            return mappedAuthorities;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuerUri);

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getOauth2().getAudience());
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuerUri);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);
        jwtDecoder.setClaimSetConverter(
            new CustomClaimConverter(clientRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId("oidc"), restTemplateBuilder.build())
        );

        return jwtDecoder;
    }
}
```

With this change I have the same error of 401 Unauthorized. So I change the SecurityFilterChain construction and I have removed for test the last part of it.

```
.and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter())
                .and()
            .and()
                .oauth2Client()
```

With this change I can access my Endpoint and I want to use Principal to read the token and have user information but the Principal is null. So, I ask you, how can I build my SecurityFilterChain to get authenticated with the jwt token from azure AD and get the Principal not null for my future development...

All I want is to have access to my java API with the Azure AD Token and read the information of user in the token with java.

Thanks